# Отладчик С++ ?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как понимать под отладчик . Начал использовать прогу MVС++ /Начал ввести программные коды. Потом запустаю результат , появляется черный  экран.Нажимаю вводить,ни реагирует. Никаких результатов.
Знакомый говорит,что нужно смотреть под отладчик. Как понимать под отладчик? Что это значит..Может подскажите что это такое и для чего предназначена?

Comment: русский язык не понимать?

Comment: @DreamChild: думаю, мы разговариваем с google translate :)

Comment: @VladD, думаю, что транслейт бы перевел ни как "н__и__ реагирует", а как "н__е__ реагирует". хотя...

Answer (score 6):

- [раз](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn), но может быть сложно - все на китайском:)
- [а здесь оффициально](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx)
- [для самых маленьких - видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0)